# Can't get a simple onclick script to work. Probably messing up variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a very simple calculator with three input boxes and using a button to input the result in another textbox. I tried different ways and none of them seem to work. My guess is that I'm completely messing up the variables.

```
<div class="input-group col-xs-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Velocity (m/s)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="vel">
</div>

<div class="input-group col-xs-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Diameter (m)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="dia">
</div>

<div class="input-group col-xs-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Kinematic Viscosity (m&#178;/s)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="kinVis">
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="reynoldsNumber(x, y, z)">Calculate</button>

<div class="input-group col-xs-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Reynolds Number</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="reynolds" readonly>
</div>

<script>
    function reynoldsNumber(x, y, z) {
        var x = document.getElementById("vel").innerHTML;
        var y = document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML;
        var z = document.getElementById("kinVis").innerHTML;
        return (x * y) / z;
    }
    document.getElementById("reynolds").innerHTML = reynoldsNumber(x, y, z);
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script and you only  need to call onclick="reynoldsNumber()".  You don't need to pass any values through the function

Also, you can't output to the innerHTML, but you can output to the value.  Further, it is not the innerHTML that you are trying to get, but the value of the inputs.  These errors are fixed below.

```
 <script>
    function reynoldsNumber() {
      var x = document.getElementById("vel").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("dia").value;
      var z = document.getElementById("kinVis").value;

      document.getElementById("reynolds").value = (x * y) / z;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Yea this works perfectly fine, and it looks like i should go back and read a bit. Seems like basic stuff. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong that I can see. I think it might be useful for you to do a javascript tutorial or two as these are key concepts that you really should grok.

1. You are calling a function with arguments, and then assigning over the top of them. There's no point doing that
2. `document.getElementById` does exactly what it says. It gets an element with an `Id`. You have no elements with the `Id` of "vel" (or the others) - you've only got elements with a *name* of "vel"
3. If you are calling a function with arguments, the arguments need to exist in the current scope

Answer (score 0):

When calling the method, you need to supply actual values to x, y and z OR you need to define them in the global scope using `var x = [your number here]`

Same problem for the onClick listeners in your HTML code. Supply actual values instead of undefined x,y,z